# Как извлечь определенные значения из столбца и указать их количество в столбце

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Дан датасет, вот 2 колонки из него:

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['020245D5Z02255D0',  '92014947Q6252900', '02025727Y05255D0', '32024752804301S0', '32804202475301S0', '34301202475280S0'], 'Size': ['4XL', '80B', '25-27', 'S/M', 'M', 'L']}) 
print(df)
```

Мне нужно извлечь только определенные строки в столбце и построить график на основании их количества. Извлечь нужно только ('M', 'L') - посчитать их количество и построить график.

На выходе:

```
               Size   Count
0                 M     10
1                 L     50
```

1. Я делала так:

```
Sales = df.groupby(['Size'])['Name'].count()
Sales.plot()
```

но тогда выводит абсолютно все значения.

2. Затем так:

```
df.groupby('Size').apply(lambda x: x.drop('Size', axis=1).drop_duplicates().shape[0])
pandas.core.series.Series
```

Но тогда получается тип Series со всеми значениями и я не знаю как построить график.

3. Потом так:

```
df.groupby('Size').apply(lambda x: x.drop('Size', axis=1).drop_duplicates().shape[0]).to_frame('counts')
```

Получается фрейм с одной колонкой Name: counts, dtype: int64 и тоже со всеми значениями, и как тогда построить график.

4. Если делать так:

```
size_M = df[df['Size'] == 'M'].count()
size_L = df[['Size'] == 'L']
```

Я не знаю как это применить и выбрать из датафрейма эти значения.

5. `Sales.isin(['M', 'L'])`
   Если изъять все значения, получаю булевский датафрейм и тоже не знаю как это применить.

Comment: Кажется вам сюда https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html По сути берете ```df.Size.value_counts()``` и обрабатываете как надо

Answer (score 3):

```
df[df.loc[:,"Size"].isin(["M", "L"])]
```

получите:

```
               Name Size
4  32804202475301S0    M
5  34301202475280S0    L
```

еще конкретнее:

```
res = df[df.loc[:,"Size"].isin(["M", "L"])]["Size"].value_counts()
print(res)
```

```
L    1
M    1
```

Answer (score 1):

альтернативные варианты решения:

```
res = df["Size"].value_counts().loc[["M", "L"]]
```

или

```
res = df.query("Size in ['M', 'L']")["Size"].value_counts()
```

---

```
In [228]: res
Out[228]:
M    1
L    1
Name: Size, dtype: int64
```